# Can not map over a response json array

Tags: json, react-native, dictionary

I have the Json response from an api in the below format

```
[ 
  {
    id: 1,
    class: '10',
    section: 'A',
    subject: 'Social'
  },
  { 
    id: 2,
    class: '8',
    section: 'C',
    subject: 'Social'
  },
  {
  id: 3,
  class: '9',
  section: 'A',
  subject: 'Social'
  } 
]
```

I am storing the json response in a state variable and able to print the above json array successfully.

```
async ListAllTodaysClasses() {
    try {
      let data = new FormData();
      data.append('id', this.state.id)
      data.append('year',this.state.year)
      data.append('month',this.state.month)
      data.append('day', this.state.day)
      var url = this.state.url;
      console.log(url);
      let response = await fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: data
      });
      let res = await response.json();
      this.setState({
        subjects: res
      })
      console.log(this.state.subjects)
    } catch(error) {
      this.setState({error: error});
      console.log("error " + error);
    }
  }
```

Here I am trying to loop over an json response array.

```
this.state.subjects.map((item, key) => (
  <TouchableOpacity key={key}>
    <View>
      {
        <Text style={styles.textColor2}>{item.class}th-{item.section}/ {item.subject}</Text>
      }
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
))
```

But I am getting Typeerror: undefined is not a function

Comment: *"I am storing the json response in a state variable..."* Show us that. If you're *literally* storing a JSON response as as state variable, you're storing a string, and strings don't have `map`. But hopefully you're not doing that, you're parsing the JSON and storing the result, which is not JSON. Remember, JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: can you post your full component? This can't be elaborated until unless you show how you are getting the JSON and how you are displaying it. Please update your post with proper code

Comment: I have updated the code @T.J.Crowder

Comment: I have added api method to the code @AnkushRishi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with JSON. You're storing the result of calling `response.json()`, which parses the JSON in the response and returns the parsed result.

Your code to store it is correct:

```
this.setState({
  subjects: res
})
```

so I suspect the problem is in your constructor where you set your *initial* state. The correct initial state for `subjects` would be like this:

```
// In your constructor
this.state = {
    /*...any other state you have...*/,
    subjects: []
};
```

Notice that `subjects` is an empty array. I suspect you're setting it to `{}` (an empty object) or `""` (an empty string) or similar. (You're clearly not failing to initialize it, and not using `null`, since that would produce a different error.)

---

Side note: Although your `setState` call is correct, what follows it is not:

```
  this.setState({
    subjects: res
  })
  console.log(this.state.subjects) // <=== Will not see the updated state
```

Remember that [state updates are asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

Comment: @Swati - Glad that helped! Just out of curiousity, what were you setting it to before?

Comment: subjects: ''  :(  @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @Swati - :-) Thanks! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to init your `state.subjects`:

```
class YourClassName extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      subjects: []
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As I said in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56108587/157247), they're clearing initializing it with *something* (otherwise the error would be different), but just not with an array.

Comment: Yeah, that what I was thinking too. But hard to tell with only half the code.